# Can we add Pins not in collection to Map.Pins?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin project in which I'm using Xamarin.Essentials' Xamarin.Maps. I have an IObservableCollection loaded with entities which I've bound to my Map in my XAML view/page, but I would also like to add a Pin that's not in that collection to that Map manually. Can it be done or should I just forego the XAML bind and deal with Map.Pins manually?

*MyPage.xaml*

```
...
<maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" FlexLayout.Grow="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Churrerxs}">
    <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <maps:Pin x:DataType="model:MyModel" Position="{Binding PositionAttr}" Label="{Binding NameAttr}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            </maps:Map>
...
```

I've tried adding the following within `MyMap`'s definition, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
<maps:Map.Pins>
    <maps:Pin Position="{Binding MyPosition}" Label="MyPin" />
</maps:Map.Pins>
```

I've also tried creating a `Pin` on my page's constructor and adding a handler that's executed when `MyPosition` changes like so:

```
if(_viewModel.MyPosition != null)
{
    MyPin.Position = _viewModel.MyPosition;
    if (!MyMap.Pins.Contains(MyPin))
    {
        MyMap.Pins.Add(MyPin);
    }
}
```

But since `Pins` is already being manipulated by the ItemTemplate in XAML, I'm already falling into race conditions where I add the pin manually but soon enough it gets removed.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to best handle this. I wish Map could have more than a single array of Pins, so we could use bindings for different collections, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm thinking a) I should handle the collection manually, or b) instead of a Pin I should display MyPosition by drawing a circle or some other graphic that's independent from the Pins array. But I'm open to suggestions if anyone knows of a proper pattern to handle this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, rather than trying to manually shoehorn a Pin to a collection that's handled by a binding, or handling the binding manually in order to fit my "special pin" into the collection, the simplest solution is to have a `readonly Circle MyCircle` defined in your view/page, populate it with a `new Circle { Center = new Position(), Radius = Distance.FromMeters(10) }` in it's constructor and then simply updating it's position whenever it changes (note: I only add it to the map after a position has actually been acquired, otherwise it'd be impossible to draw).

```
if(_viewModel.MyPosition != null)
{
    MyCircle.Center = _viewModel.MyPosition;
    if (!MyMap.MapElements.Contains(MyCircle))
    {
        MyMap.MapElements.Add(MyCircle);
    }
}
```

It's left as an exercise to the reader to figure out how to handle input if need be (I don't need to interact with the circle, just display it).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT you can't mark your own answer as the answer sooner than 48hs after posting it, I will after that countdown's up :)